# useRef not update

Tags: next.js, accordion, use-ref

Can someone help me to understand why the contentHeight doesnt update?
it seems that contentEl (useRef) is not updating correctly.

If u check the "LONG CONTENT" accordion item, u can see the content height is so much short and the content text remains hide. :(

Codesandbox preview: https://pb6coe.sse.codesandbox.io/

Codesandobx code: https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-with-useref-pb6coe?file=/pages/index.js

I tried to console.log the contentEl for every click but the value is always the last accordion items -.-

Ty for helps

Comment: Did you check the below answer with the sandbox? I think it can help you in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you only set a single ref initially for content and `useEffect` with your setup run once solely after the component is mounted, so that's why it's always referred to the same content element.

I'd suggest that you should use one ref for all content elements by indexes.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-with-useref-forked-prcfuc?file=/pages/index.js:0-2492)

```js
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { project } from "../data";

function IndexPage() {
  //initialize a list of content elements
  const contentEl = useRef([]);
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState();

  const handleToggle = (index) => {
    if (clicked === index) {
      return setClicked("0");
    }
    setClicked(index);
  };

  return (
    <StyledAccordion>
      {project.map((prj, index) => {
        const { title, text, location, description, date } = prj;

        return (
          <StyledItem className={clicked === index ? "active" : ""} key={index}>
            <StyledButton onClick={() => handleToggle(index)}>
              <StyledInfo>
                <div className="title">{title}</div>
                <div className="text">{text}</div>
                <div>{location}</div>
                <div>{date}</div>
              </StyledInfo>
              <span>{clicked === index ? "—" : "+"} </span>
            </StyledButton>

            <StyledContent
              ref={(node) => (contentEl.current[index] = node)}
              contentHeight={
                contentEl.current[index]
                  ? contentEl.current[index].scrollHeight
                  : 0
              }
              active={clicked === index}
            >
              <StyledDescription>{description}</StyledDescription>
            </StyledContent>
          </StyledItem>
        );
      })}
    </StyledAccordion>
  );
}

const StyledAccordion = styled.div`
  margin: 1em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
`;

const StyledItem = styled.li``;
const StyledButton = styled.button`
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  span {
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
`;

const StyledContent = styled.div`
  height: ${(props) => (props.active ? `${props.contentHeight}px` : "0px")};
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
`;

const StyledInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2rem;

  div {
    width: 20%;
  }

  .title {
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: "Saira Extra Condensed";
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .text {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
`;

const StyledDescription = styled.div`
  background: rgb(255 134 215);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
`;

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Awesome! thanks...
but i dont understood how works this fix:

`ref={(node) => (contentEl.current[index] = node)}
              contentHeight={
                contentEl.current[index]
                  ? contentEl.current[index].scrollHeight
                  : 0
              }`

Can u explain what happen there?

Comment: for the first rendering, `contentEl.current[index]` is not there, so that's why I added a ternary condition in `contentHeight` to make sure no errors initially. `ref={contentEl}` (your previous implementation) is technically a shortcut in getting node as a reference for `contentEl`. Now I'm just passing a function to make it more obvious in populating nodes to an array of references instead. @sedprc

Comment: thanks man!
Now everything is clear!